# Manual load and removal of entries with AsyncCache in Caffeine

Tags: java, asynchronous, caffeine

I'm just a starter with Caffeine cache and needs clarification for few use cases.

1. I see Caffeine supports invalidate/invalidateAll function only for Synchronous cache. I would like to know why invalidate function is not supported for AsyncCache?

```
asyncCache.synchronous().invalidate(key) //supported for synchronous cache                                    
asyncCache.invalidate(key)// not supported for async cache
```

2. Also wanted to clarify whether the put method in AsyncCache, loads entry into the cache Asynchronously? I wanted to manually add the list of entries into the AsyncCache. Not sure either asyncCache.asMap().putAll() or iterating and adding the entries using asyncCache.put() does the job asynchronously?

Can someone please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since the method is available in the `synchronous()` view, it would only be a convenience default method making that same call. Since `invalidate` does not return a value, it does not need to block after the future was removed from the underlying `Map`. If a blocking removal was desired, that is available through `synchronous().asMap().remove(key)`. It didn't seem to carry its weight.
2. An `AsyncCache` stores a `CompletableFuture` as the entry's value. A `put` of a future only blocks long enough to perform the `ConcurrentHashMap` operation, allowing the future to be resolved independently. If the future completes as an error or null result, then a `whenComplete` handler removes it from the cache. This way establishing the Map entry is synchronous, but loading the future's value is asynchronous.

Caffeine can be thought of as a bounded Map with convenience APIs to orient towards caching problems. It should behave how you might expect when using `ConcurrentHashMap` explicitly instead. Therefore, `Cache<K, V>` ~= `Map<K, V>` and `AsyncCache<K, V>` ~= `Map<K, CompletableFuture<V>>`. When the cache apis are too restrictive then using an `asMap` view provides all of the functionality the cache interface implementation classes use.